# FileInput when triggered by label "for" event returns no file path

Tags: php, html, css

I'm attempting to make the file input field in HTML a lot prettier by covering it up. However I still need to be able to trigger the event of selecting a file.

```
<form action="scripts/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <label for="fileToUpload" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Select an Image</label>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Upload Image</button>
</form>
```

When using the `for="fileToUpload"` system, it will open the dialog box and the input field does receive a file path value (I've checked with JS). However this seems to be rather superficial. When passing it on from the form, it disappears.

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
```

This line results in an empty string.
If I leave out my attempts to style and instead stick with using the default button, it works just fine.

[image: Image buttons.]

I've also attempted JS click events on the input field with the same results. Why will it only properly select files when using the default button?

Comment: Hi, please put CSS styles for part of code that you paste in question.

Comment: @GandalftheGay I've left that out because even with no styling adding, I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Before I wrote this comment above, I tried to reproduce the issue and I didn't get empty string like you. [Check this fiddle with code I used](https://jsfiddle.net/tester500/2u4ew8Lr/7/). If you want to run it by yourself need also on normal server, there is just for share you. As you can see there on screen shot, this form works fine for me. Maybe is not a problem with code but server? If you still want to resolve paste your full part of code that you use and I will check it and try help ;)